# Infinite scrolling logo loop not working properly in safari

Tags: css, safari, css-animations

I followed this tutorial
[How To Build A CSS-Only Infinite Logo Slider In WordPress With Oxygen](https://youtu.be/UQJ8o5xckvc)

but not in Oxygen, I don't think the builder matters for something like this - I used Bricksbuilder. And I did 2 things differently.

1. Created a query loop for the logos out of a custom post type
2. Used SVG logos instead of PNGs

Which I also think shouldn't make a difference, but I am including it just in case.
It runs perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari doesn't seem to 'display' the first iteration of the logo set. It's clearly there if use my mouse and click in the region - it's just not rendering off canvas... but the set with the delay is rendering.

Here is the CSS:
[CSS-Only Logo Slider](https://gist.github.com/Spellhammer/e5b61896869ba448f2bec9b9b44730e3)

I'm still pretty new to CSS, this is by far the most complicated thing I have ever pulled off, and I still don't understand it 100%
It would be nice to know why this happens, and how to fix it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This link should help you put a runnable snippet direct into your question so we can see the problem for ourselves https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example